# C++ How can I handle errors within my code for Combinations and Permutations?

Tags: c++, error-handling

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int fact(int num) 
{
  if(num==1) 
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else 
  {
    return num * fact(num-1);
  }
}

int main() 
{
  int n, r, nPr, nCr;
  string userInput;

  try
  {
    cout << "Enter two integers: ";
    cin >> n >> r;
```

So right here, I want to implement a check to see if n and r are integers, the only way I can think of is to make it if (isdigit()) but I don't know how i'd put two variables into one statement. As well as that I want to implement a check to see if the numbers are n >=r >= 0, which Im guessing id have to do before the if statement discussed above, being a for statement. However yet again, since its two variables Im slightly confused on to how id go by doing so.

EDIT: I think I figured out how to do the two isdigits
correct me if im wrong,

```
if (isdigit(n) && isdigit(r))


    cout << "Please enter 'p' for permutation or 'c' for combination" << endl;
    cin >> userInput;

    nPr = fact(n)/fact(n-r);

    nCr = nPr/fact(r);

    if (userInput == "p")
    {
      cout << "permutations of " << n << " and " << r << " = " << nPr << endl;
    } 
    else if (userInput == ("c"))
    {  
      cout << "combinations of " << n << " and " << r << " = " << nCr << endl;
    }
    else
    {
      throw runtime_error("invalid input");
    }
  }
  catch (runtime_error& excpt)
  {
    cout << "error: " << excpt.what() << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin.fail()` will be true if input (including conversion from typed chars to `int` values) failed.

Comment: By the way, the expression `fact(n)/fact(n-r)` will exceed the number range of `int` long before a more direct calculation, using a loop, would.